# remove first 32 characters from first line in file

Tags: python, string, file

I have a long text file that always begins with a 32-character MD5 hash, like so:

`f4f494da100a3577420a7ff7c32abb5707:55:40 PM | username: text`

My goal is to strip the first 32 characters of the first line of this file, then overwrite the line. My code (below) successfully grabs the line and strips the characters, but erases everything else in the file.

```
with open(x, 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    lines = lines[0]
    lines = lines[32:]
with open(x, 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fout.write(line)
```

I know that I can edit the first line with `lines[0]` but I am not sure how to remove the characters that way (maybe `re`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just manually read the first 32 characters then call `readlines` to read the rest:

```
with open(x, 'r') as fin:
    header = fin.read(32)
    lines = fin.readlines()
with open(x, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lines[0]` is fine - the only problem is that you're overwriting your `lines` variable, thus losing the other lines:

```
with open(x, 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    lines[0] = lines[0][32:] # Strip just the first line
with open(x, 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, but it still overwrites the whole file with just the first line.

Comment: @celestialroad is it possible that the file has already been overridden by your code and this is just taking that one line that was remaining and working with it?